# Mount user-specific Samba shares using cifs

Tags: mount, fstab, cifs

I managed to mount my Synology NAS Samba shares appending `/etc/fstab` with the following lines:

```
//192.168.1.91/shared /media/shared cifs uid=viktor,credentials=/home/viktor/.champignac,user,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
//192.168.1.91/home /media/home cifs uid=viktor,credentials=/home/viktor/.champignac,user,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
//192.168.1.91/photo /media/photo cifs uid=viktor,credentials=/home/viktor/.champignac,user,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

How ever, I would like for every user to log in to these shares using their own credentials which map the `/home` share to their own directory. How would I approach this? Is this possible using `fstab` and `cifs`?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might have a look at [autofs](https://serverfault.com/questions/219615/mount-cifs-share-with-autofs) and modify `/etc/auto.smb` to match your needs.